# Sitecore RSS Feed Error

Tags: rss, sitecore, feed

I'm trying to properly configure my RSS feed through Sitecore. I'm getting this error:

"**Feed is not configured properly, the feed cannot be rendered. Check Sitecore log for full error report.**
Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\CabotTwo\WebSite\bin\Support.323326.FeedRenderer.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Unfortunately, I have no real experience at all with Sitecore. Does anybody know what I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a reference to a DLL from Sitecore product support. Is that assembly mentioned in your Web.config? Is it present in your bin directory?

Comment: I can't seem to find it at all :/ I don't know how to add it into Web.config - like how to reference it.

Comment: Well perhaps try something simple -- search in your Web.config and other files under App_Config for 323326.